# cd and ls in the same call

Tags: ls, cd-command

I often have to `cd` to a directory and `ls` to see the directory listing. Can it be done with one shot, so that I can add to `.bashrc` as alias. I searched on Google, there were some answers, but incomplete.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the question, but can't you just (instead of **cd dir; ls**  ) just do **ls dir**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that this means that you want to still be in the directory after `ls` has run, if not, just run `ls` with the dir as an argument.

```
cl() {
    cd "$@" && ls
}
```

```
foo$ mkdir bar
foo$ > bar/baz
foo$ > bar/qux
foo$ cl bar
baz  qux
bar$
```

Comment: Where do I put the cl() function into , in the bashrc?

Comment: @MotiurRahman Yes, and then source your `~/.bashrc` from `~/.bash_profile`.